# bash script 4 rows in one line

Tags: bash, awk

I have file like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

How to get result like that by awk or similar:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: For a highly rated sed solution (and an additional awk solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $(cat file)
```

if the file is short.

```
awk '{printf("%s ",$0)}' <file
```

if you want awk or similar.

Comment: In `bash` you can say `echo $(<file)` too.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -sd\  infile
```

Note that the above command contains two white space characters (an escaped and a plain one).

Comment: Great, I always forget what these commands like `paste`, `join` do :) — I usually write it as `-sd' '` in here to avoid explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf $0" "}' your_file
```

Comment: Now put `%s` into `your_file` :)

Comment: Do I have to? I usually put `%s` and other stuff when I need formatting. I use `printf` mostly to kill the `newline`. May be there is something to it that I am not aware.

Comment: I mean, if the file contains `'%s'`, then it will be interpreted as a format string and will error out. I also used `printf` to kill the newline, but differently (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -l40pe1 infile
```